# EcmaScript Спецификация или язык программирования?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript

Русская версия

> ECMAScript — это встраиваемый расширяемый не имеющий средств
>   ввода-вывода язык программирования, используемый в качестве основы для
>   построения других скриптовых языков. Стандартизирован международной
>   организацией ECMA в спецификации ECMA-262. Расширения языка:
>   JavaScript, JScript и ActionScript.

Английская версия

> ECMAScript (or ES) is a trademarked scripting-language specification
>   standardized by Ecma International in ECMA-262 and ISO/IEC 16262.

1. Так всё-таки EcmaScript это спецификация или язык программирования? Получается в Вики ошибка или что?

   Текст написан про EcmaScript в русской вики

   > Язык возник на основе нескольких технологий, самыми известными из
   >   которых являются языки JavaScript и JScript. Разработка первой
   >   редакции спецификации началась в ноябре 1996 года.
2. Получается язык как они говорят EcmaScript возник на основе нескольких технологий аля: JavaScript и JScript. То есть слияние этих всех технологий или языков? Или наоборот на примере JavaScript(a): Это EcmaScript + DOM, BOM и еще что-нибудь? Я правильно понимаю?

Да я копаю в основы и тд. Уж лучше так медленней понимать и знать что да как, чем после 20 минут JavaScript(a) идти во фреймворки и  пытаться понять как там всё работает -_-

Comment: Лично я очень сомневаюсь к компетентности `Вики`... Если конечно я правильно понял и речь сайте `wikipedia`

Comment: @Air да википедия

Comment: @Air нет)))))))

Comment: Что вы к словам цепляетесь. Спецификация в данном случае синоним "описание". "Описание языка.." - так понятнее?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для разбора откроем саму [спецификацию](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/) (последний черновик)

Название явно указывает:

> ECMAScript® 2019 Language Specification

> Спецификация языка ECMAScript® 2019

---

Далее во введении можно увидеть следующее:

> Этот Ecma стандарт определяет **язык** ECMAScript 2019. Это десятая редакция спецификации языка ECMAScript.

> ECMAScript основан на нескольких технологиях, таких как JavaScript (Netscape) и JScript (Microsoft).

> Настоящий **стандарт определяет язык программирования** общего назначения ECMAScript 2019.

---

Далее идет секция соответствия, в которой указывается определенные пункты, которым должна соответствовать **реализация** ECMAScript.

---

Из всего выше сказанного можно сделать вывод:

1. Есть языковая спецификация
2. Спецификация описывает язык ECMAScript
3. Есть конкретные реализации этой спецификации, например `JavaScript`

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван, нет. BOM, DOM и все такое - это отдельная вещь по сути никак к javascript  не относящаяся. Это interface которые предоставляет host объект. Например в том же nodejs, никаких BOM и DOM нет, а javascript есть.

Comment: Получается EcmaScript это слияние разных технологий и языков программирования аля JavaScript и JScript?

Comment: Ну допустим JavaScript + JScript + разные технологии или языки программирования = EcmaScript?

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван не совсем :-) сначала netscape выпустил javascript, потом ie сделал свою реализацию, и в итоге решили как-то все обобщить и структурировать. Так появилась спецификация, которой в большей или меньшей степени сейчас соответствуют все реализации.

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван, _Ну допустим JavaScript + JScript + разные технологии или языки программирования = EcmaScript?_ - опять же не совсем :-)

Comment: спасибо, мало чего понятно покамись, но всё равно спасибо.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87989/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Answer (score 3):

Спецификация языка - это документ, который описывает язык. Чтобы язык начал свое существование, он должен быть описан.

В самой спецификации ECMAScript во введении написано:

> This Ecma Standard defines the ECMAScript 2015 Language.

Так что никакого противоречия нет.

В приведенной вами цитате

> Язык возник на основе нескольких технологий, самыми известными из
>   которых являются языки JavaScript и JScript.

язык программирования определяется как вид информационной технологии.

Comment: Получается это спецификация это документ который описывает язык. Тогда интересно почему не написали что это и язык программирования и спецификация имеется. А на второй вопрос ответите?)

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван Любой язык начинает свое существование после того, как он описан, то есть идентифицирован в мире информационных технологий.

Comment: Ну, не любой язык и не всегда. Например, описание [awk dark corners](https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_2.html#SEC7) появилось лет через 15 после создания первой версии языка

Comment: @avp  Чтобы язык идентифицировать, он в любом случае должен быть описан в какой-либо спецификации,и не важно, стандартизирована ли она или нет

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, да, в теории. На практике же (когда делают для себя) актуальной спецификацией иногда являются лишь сорсы... (хорошо еще если комментарии в них актуальны -))

Comment: @avp Когда вы делаете для себя, то никому нет дела, что там на вашем персональном компьютере. Речь же идет о сообществе программистов и сфере информационных технологий.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, "для себя" -- на самом деле я имел в виду "внутрифирменные проекты" (не по контракту с внешним заказчиком (хотя и с ними не все всегда как в теории должно быть (это же реальная жизнь...))), то чем будут пользоваться несколько (десятков?) человек. Да и в ограниченном внешнем мире (на гите и т.п.) таких полным полно...

Comment: @avp Все равно существует некоторое описание либо отдельным документом, либо в виде комментариев в коде. Но если выносится на рассмотрение сообществу программистов, требуется спецификация того, что предлагается.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, я не говорю, что отсутствие полной спецификации это хорошо. Но если на какую-нибудь либу, которая вот прямо сейчас решает вашу текущую задачу нет документации, а есть, ну скажем, неформальное описание (примеры) того что нужно, неужели не воспользуетесь? А потом ведь и своим друзьям предложите. Так оно и пошло-поехало (без нормальных спецификаций...)